# Hello World on dos cmd line does not return - elementary C - I have to close cmd after every execution

Tags: c, cmd, output

A simple Hello World in C on command line

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() 
 {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

I compile with tcc and 
when I execute I see no output
and cannot get another command prompt.  I have to close the cmd.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Console programs open in an existing console if started from one or open a new console if started by other means like double clicking. A new console will only have your program in it not CMD.exe.

Comment: Can you set your compiler options so that all warnings are enabled and edit your message with the potential output ?